# match two strings with letters in random order in python

Tags: python, regex

if I have 2 strings like:

```
a = "hello"
b = "olhel"
```

I want to use a regular expression (or something else?) to see if the two strings contain the same letters. In my example a would = b because they have the same letters. How can this be achieved?

Comment: If the counts of each letter can be ignored, you can simply use `set(a) == set(b)`, which is faster than `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`

Comment: @Satoru Logic: I would have voted for your comment if it was an answer.  I'd post it myself but that would be sleazy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = "hello"
b = "olhel"
print sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

Comment: in a simple example, like yours, it works flawlessly. but in my hangman game, it does the same thing (I printed the strings to check that they are equal) it doesent work. Could you please tell me whats wrong? code:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10141934/hangman.py (line 230)

Comment: You'll have to debug for yourself.  Print out the sorted values and see how they're inequal.  Case?  Whitespace?  Different length?

Answer (score 4):

An O(n) algorithm is to create a dictionary of counts of each letter and then compare the dictionaries.

In Python 2.7 or newer this can be done using [**`collections.Counter`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('hello') == Counter('olhel')
True
```

Comment: @Rafe with another example of the meaninglessness of the buzzword "Pythonic".

Comment: It certainly has no meaning where you just used it.  What were you trying to say?  "In a Python-specific manner" is hardly a positive trait.  There's nothing seriously wrong with this solution (at a glance, anyway), but it's in no way more natural as Python code than mine.

Comment: @Mark: I think this is O(m log n), where m is the length of the string and n is the number of distinct letters.  You're iterating over every letter (m), then finding the letter in the underlying dict of n entries.  In practice, since dict is a hash table, it'll probably perform close to O(n) for smaller values of n, but if you throw lots of distinct characters at it (eg. CJK) it'll probably degrade significantly.

Comment: @Glenn: I suppose I see what you mean, but I don't think complementing someone for using Python to its fullest is a bad thing.

Comment: @Glenn: where does the log n come from?  n is bounded by a small constant, hence updating ocurrences of letters should be O(1).

Comment: @Sheldon: n isn't inherently bounded, and may be large for some languages.  Of course, the OP is probably just solving word scrambles for CS102, where it wouldn't matter if it was O(n^2).